# Uninstall Android App without user interaction

Tags: android, uninstallation, interaction

If you have superuser permissions you can delete apk file from data/app but app list don't refresh if you don't reboot phone, so I don't know how can I uninstall one app without user interaction, or how can I refresh app list without reboot phone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im guessing for the normal non-rooted phone, this is not possible. That would allow people with bad intentions way too much power.

Comment: @trgraglia yes but if you have rooted phone exist some way?

Comment: @trgraglia because titanium backup can uninstall without android default uninstaller.

Comment: Maybe it just deletes the apk file from the data/app folder? That is the same as uninstalling it. And the list is easy enough to refresh.

Comment: Ok now I delete apk file, how can I refresh android app list?

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure about superuser stuff. Perhaps that is a question for XDA Developers.

Comment: It's ok, i have already posted this in xda, I have another idea of how to do this, perhaps if I reload the launcher the list will be refreshed on it's own. Anyone know how can this be done? Maybe is possible to close the activy using an intent? or calling the package and closing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is another question all together. I would post another question with that. Also, some code snippets may help people understand what you are getting at.

Comment: Thx and congrats on your new badge. :o)

Comment: @Hamid can we delete apk from data/app folder without root access, and is it like the application will no longer be accessible in device ?

Comment: @pyus13 I'm afraid not. Without root access, the /data folder appears "empty". It is inaccessible, so you are unable to browse to /data/app and remove the apk. Your best option is to check the PackageManager APIs and see what that has to offer. At the least, it should allow updating the package list, IF you can find a way to remove the app (without root). With root, it's a simple case of deleting the apk from /data/app and then refresh the list (somehow). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

Comment: @Hamid i got your point but then how the product like Maass360 providing the feature of selective wipe for the applications just check it out http://www.maas360.com/products/mobile-device-management/android/ because as per i think we can not even delete the data of other applications.

Comment: @pyus13 I'm not familiar with this Maass360 but I assume, glancing at their site that the application registers itself as a Device Administrator with a security policy that allows it administrative (essentially, root) access. Other applications like AntiVirus software and mobile security suites, as well as MS Exchange do the same thing to allow administrative control over the device via said security policies, for example to remotely wipe or lock a device, and such.